# xlsxwriter chart categories file size

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

The following code takes a CSV as input and output an XLSX containing a bar chart:

```
import pandas
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

# ---- Data preparation ----
path = sys.argv[1]
df = pandas.read_csv(path, sep = "\t")
df = df[pandas.notnull(df['response_time'])]
df.loc[:, "datetime"].replace(to_replace = r"(.*T)", value = r"", inplace = True, regex = True)
df = pandas.pivot(df.datetime, df.name + '-' + df.type, df.response_time)

# ---- Prepare writer, workbook and worksheet ----
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "graph")
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["graph"]

# ---- USING OPENPYXL ----
chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.x_axis_title = "DateTime"
chart1.x_axis_title = "Response time"
data = Reference(workbook.active, min_col = 2, min_row = 1, max_col = len(df.columns) + 1, max_row = workbook.active.max_row)
xval = Reference(workbook.active, min_col = 1, min_row = 2, max_row = workbook.active.max_row)
chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data = True)
chart1.set_categories(xval)
workbook.active.add_chart(chart1, "D4")
workbook.save("test.xlsx")

# ---- USING XLSXWRITER ----
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type' : 'column'})
for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    chart.add_series({
        'name' : ['graph', 0, i],
        'values' : ['graph', 1, i, len(df.index), i],
        'categories': ['graph', 1, 0, len(df.index), 0],
    })
chart.set_x_axis({'name' : 'DateTime'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name' : 'Response Time'})
worksheet.insert_chart('D4', chart)
writer.save()
```

Output graph is:

[image]

Both the openpyxl and xlsxwriter versions produce the exact same graph. The problem is that the xlsxwriter version output graph is 10MB but the openpyxl is only 3MB.

After investigating, I found out that it's the 'categories' entry in the xlsxwriter version that increases the weight considerably.

When I comment it, my X axis is now a serie from 1 to n but the output is only 1.6MB, how is that possible ? How can I make the output more lightweight using xlsxwriter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XlsxWriter file is probably bigger due to the fact that it stores the chart category and data values for the chart as well as for the worksheet, like Excel does. This gives better fidelity with Excel produced files, which is a goal of XlsxWriter, and also causes less issues when the charts are embedded in other applications, such as PowerPoint.

I’d guess from your analysis that openpyxl doesn’t store the additional data.

If you resave the XlsxWriter, or openpyxl, file in Excel I would expect that you end up with a file size that is approximately the same as the XlsxWriter file.

Comment: Wow you're right, I save it when the size is the almost the same as xlsxwriter. I guess I will stay with the xlsxwriter version since it's a bit faster and for the reasons you said. Thanks for the explanations

Comment: Storing the values in the chart is entirely optional, which is why openpyxl doesn't do it. It also isn't really practicable if you have formulae. But openpyxl can also read charts which means you can create templates in Excel.

If speed is that important I'd probably avoid using Pandas altogether and just stream from the CSV to XLSX.

Comment: @CharlieClark Pandas is blazing fast and doesn't use much memory. Longest part is creating the chart and saving it. Pandas transformations (using pivot etc, as I did) only takes 40ms for 500 000 rows dataframe

Comment: Pandas `to_excel()` method is not particularly fast when compared with working directly with the dataframe. But what would I know?

Comment: @CharlieClark But how could I create the chart which uses the dataframe data without write it to excel first ?